# What does this superscript on HypergeometricPFQ mean?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I was messing around with some integrals and I got as output the following:

[image: Integral]
What does the superscript on the last term in that expression mean? I looked at the documentation for `HypergeometricPFQ`, but it did not contain any such superscripts. That hypergeometric function numerically evaluates to $\approx-0.5386594533$.

Comment: I think this question about derivatives being shown as superscripts has been asked a number of times already...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first guess when I see parenthesized exponents is that this represents a derivative of a multivariate expression. To check this guess I try

```
FullForm[%]
```

and look at what that shows me. That confirms there is a `Derivative` wrapped around your `HypergeometricPFQ`

If I use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate` to get an approximate result instead of an exactly precise result then it approximates all that and gives about 0.40978 for your integral and doesn't include any derivatives in the result.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the case.